# Which Distribution CDH Vs HDP

Tags: cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm, hortonworks-sandbox

I happened to work on CDH longtime back ( around 1 year) and am planning to start again.Now we had CDH , HDP and Hortonwork acquired by Cloudera .

1. Is HDP being developed actively ? Or Is CDH being developed actively ?
2. Which distribution I should get started with ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloudera (the company behind CDH) and Hortonworks (the company behind HDP) have merged. They now are called Cloudera.

After the merger a new distribution was released, called the [Cloudera Data Platform](https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-data-platform.html), or CDP in short.

Though both older platforms will still exist for a short while, all new users should go for CDP. This is the platform that is seeing all development focus.

Note that the situation may be more nuanced if your company is already a heavy user of either HDP/CDH but even in those cases the formal recommendation is still to go to CDP as soon as possible.

---

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera (formerly Hortonworks), the company behind CDP as well as HDP and CDH.

Comment: Does CDP offer sandboxes like for CDH - this is evaluate the product ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is something in the Cloud, but if you want to use your own hardware I believe this is currently the only way. It should not have any restrictions that the sandbox did not have, outside perhaps a time limitation.

Comment: can you point me to the sandboxes ? I didnt seem to find a direct link.

Comment: @Nag Check out this excellent community article, it has an explanation of how to get a sandbox like experience using the trial: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-create-a-Centos7-CDP-DC-Trial-VM-for-sandbox-learning/ta-p/300837

Comment: Just an update on this thread. Effective Jan 2021, all the CDP and HDP require a subscription to download, by keeping the legacy/existing versions for free. Obviously, they would be outdated and will not have any active developments. Reference: https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/paywall-expansion.html